# Attribuer un score : « scorer » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, sport

Je cherche un verbe pour dire ***attribuer un score***, et le nom de la procédure correspondante.

[*Scorer*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/scorer) est bien dans le Wiktionnaire, mais seulement listé comme intransitif, pas dans le sens que je recherche. Et d'après l'Académie française, [on ne le dit pas](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/scorer), parce que c'est un anglicisme pour dire *marquer* (un but, par exemple).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Généralement. Il s'agit de « [*noter*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/noter) », dans le sens de donner une *appréciation accompagnée de la note chiffrée* et incidemment de « [*corriger*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/corriger) », « [e]n partic., dans le domaine de l'enseignement. Relever les écarts en vue de noter et faire respecter la norme. *Corriger des devoirs* » (*TLFi*). Dans une autre [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14138) on parle aussi d'[*évaluer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9valuer), pour déterminer la valeur.

Contexte sportif. On a le « [*pointeur*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pointeur) » : « 4. *SPORTS.* Personne qui enregistre les résultats obtenus par les concurrents dans une compétition. (Dict.xxes.). » (*TLFi*, voir aussi [*GDT*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8413731), et surtout au [*Termium*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=ent&srchtxt=SCORE%20KEEPER)). Les verbes qui sont utilisés dans les définitions/explications sont « *enregistrer* » (les points), « *inscrire* » (les points), et « *tenir* » (le pointage). On voit aussi dans le *secrétaire aux notes*/*de la compétition* l'idée d'*écrire officiellement*. Il faut peut-être se méfier un peu de « [*pointer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pointer) »; il y a le sens plus traditionnel de « *cocher* » ou « [r]epérer d'un point, d'une marque des éléments répertoriés sur une liste, dans un registre, quand on les a contrôlés. ». Mais il y a aussi plusieurs autres sens bien établis, incluant avec le *jeu de boules*, par opposition à tirer (voir *TLFi*, pointer<sup>3</sup>). On dit aussi « [*arbitrer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/arbitrer) », du rôle de faire appliquer les règles (quoique le pointage fasse sans doute l'objet de règles). Enfin, on peut « [*juger*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/juger) » de l'habileté etc. (voir généralement l'[*arbitre sportif*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitre_sportif)).

Comment: *Noter* convient bien, et le sens additionnel de *porter un jugement*, qui souligne que c'est l'évaluateur qui détermine la note, au contraire des sports, va aussi dans la bonne direction. Merci !

Answer (score 3):

Dans le lien académique de votre question vous avez la réponse :

> *Marquer* [le résultat], [le score] s'il s'agit de sport.

Marquer est le résultat de l'attribution d'un score, sinon :

> L'arbitre ou le correcteur donne le score ou le résultat.

Synonyme possible :

> Après avoir été *attribué* par l'arbitre/le correcteur le score/résultat a été  *enregistré*.

*Scorer* n'est pas audible dans l'hexagone.

Comment: En effet, [marquer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/marquer); d'abord _marquer les points_ avec les jeux, puis ensuite, par métonymie, avec _marquer un but_ dans le sens de gagner un point; le sens diffère selon le complément, et même selon le sport. Bien intéressant! Merci.

Comment: Le problème de l'arbitre, c'est qu'il n'attribue pas le score, il ne fait que le reconnaitre. Ce sont les joueurs, par leurs actions, qui s'attribuent des points (à leur équipe) : certes, ils marquent. Si j'attribue le score de 5 à cette réponse en l'upvotant, je ne marque pas (à la rigueur, c'est la réponse qui marquerait un point).

Comment: *Attribuer* de ‘répartir entre les tribus’ : §1 « Allouer (qqch à qqn) dans un partage, une répartition » [selon le Robert], c’est le rôle de l’arbitre en fin de rencontre $2 « Considérer comme propre (à qqn ou qqch.) », c’est le point de vue des joueurs par rapport à leur équipe. $3 « Rapporter (qqch.) à un auteur, une cause ; mettre sur le compte de », c’est le rôle de l’arbitre après un coup gagnant §4 "Attribuer à soi, se donner en partage (une chose matérielle ou morale), le public en cas de victoire de leur équipe : « ON a gagné », sinon,  ILS ont perdus. L'Académie donne un bon exemple.

Answer (score 2):

Le mieux qui me vienne à l'esprit est ***évaluer***, parce qu'il s'agit bien de faire l'*évaluation* de quelque chose et d'en conclure une valeur numérique.

Problème : généralement, une évaluation est approximative (comme une estimation), ou seulement mentale (*évaluer ses chances*), et est peu associée à une note. Et puis, il me semble que l'*évaluation* désigne plus  souvent la valeur résultante que le processus d'évaluation lui-même.

Answer (score 1):

Il y a “[classer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/classer),” peut-être pas pour attribuer les « scores/notes » individus, mais pour « [a]ttribuer officiellement un rang, une place, selon le mérite ou la valeur, le rang étant exprimé ou suggéré par le contexte. Classer un élève, un candidat. » (définition II.-A. à CNRTL)

Et puis [classement](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/classement) pour la procédure.

Comment: J'ai l'impression (peut-être fautive) que *classer* comme *ranger,  trier* et ensuite *archiver* se réfère a des objets ou à des entités normées, à quelque chose qui a pu/dû d'abord être mis en chiffres ;  *scored* de par son origine sportive est liée à l'instant, au moment de l'action et aux personnes vivantes et donc ordonne des êtres singuliers ou le résultat de leurs actions.

Comment: *Individus* étant un nom, plutôt : « notes/scores » individuels (en mettant le masculin au plus près de l'adjectif pour éviter un recalcule de l'accord à la lecture).

Answer (score 1):

C'est effectivement un anglicisme.

En bon français, on dirait "marquer des points".
La raison pour laquelle il est inclus dans le wiktionnaire est l'usage je pense, certainement très utilisé dans les commentaires sportifs.
Le wiktionnaire n'est pas un dictionnaire du français, au vrai sens du terme (ce qui doit ou non figurer dans un dictionnaire de français, c'est du ressort de l'Académie) , mais, comme on trouve des dictionnaires d'expressions ou d'argot.

Il se rapproche d'un dictionnaire d'usage, comme le célèbre Urban Dictionary.
Il ne fait absolument pas référence, chacun peut y rajouter les phrases ou expressions qu'il veut.

La forme "scorer" est introuvable dans le Trésor Informatisé de la Langue Française:
http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/score

Answer (score 1):

"Marquer des points" est l'expression usuelle, cependant, les linguistes notent une augmentation de l'utilisation de l'anglicisme "scorer" en France, du coup il commence à apparaître dans les dictionnaires :
http://dictionnaire.cordial-enligne.fr/definition/scorer

Comment: Marquer des points est pour soi-même (ou son équipe), tandis que je parle d'attribuer un score à quelque chose (d'externe à nous).